# Reassign a field in child classes (clean code)

Tags: c#, oop, coding-style

Below, you will find a code snippet I have written for a program simulating a bank account.

I am wondering whether there is a cleaner way to design the inheritance for the `friendlyName` field?

Ideally, I would have stored it as a `const`, but it prevents from reasigning its value in child classes.

Thanks a lot!

```
public abstract class Account
{
   protected string friendlyName;
   public string ShowBalance()
   {
      var message = new StringBuilder();
      message.Append($"Your {friendlyName} balance is {Balance}");
             .Append("See you soon!");
      return message.ToString();
   }
}

public class SavingsAccount : Account
{
    public SavingsAccount()
    {
       friendlyName = "savings account";
    }
}

public class CurrentAccount : Account
{
   public CurrentAccount()
   {
      friendlyName = "current account";
   }
}
```

Comment: You can make friendlyName abstract so all derived classes must inherit from it, or make it virtual (optional)

Comment: Thanks @GHDevOps! Yet, to make it abstract it cannot be a field, it must be a protected property, right?

Comment: you can make it protected: protected abstract string friendlyName {get;set;}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it `const` as it would need to be initialized when it is declared. You could make it `readonly` and set it in the children constructors and this gets as close to `const` as you can with values that aren't compile-time constants.

```
public abstract class Account
{
   protected readonly string friendlyName;
   // the rest is the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it an abstract property. Inheriting, non-abstract classes then must override it

```cs
public abstract class Account
{
   protected abstract string FriendlyName { get; }

   ...
}

public class SavingsAccount : Account
{
    protected override string FriendlyName => "savings account";
}

public class CurrentAccount : Account
{
    protected override string FriendlyName => "current account";
}
```